# Python Plotly format axis numbers as %

Tags: python, formatting, plotly

Here's the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1":[0.00143,0.00653,0.00732],"col_2":[0.00984,0.00192,0.00751]},index=['A','B','C'])
```

Here's my plotly code:

```
trace0 = go.Bar(
x=[df.columns[0],df.columns[1]],
y=[df.ix[0,0],df.ix[0,1]],
name=df.index[0],
# marker=dict(color=cof_pal[0]
)


trace1 = go.Bar(
x=[df.columns[0],df.columns[1]],
y=[df.ix[1,0],df.ix[1,1]],
name=df.index[1],
# marker=dict(color=cof_pal[1]
)



trace2 = go.Bar(
x=[df.columns[0],df.columns[1]],
y=[df.ix[2,0],df.ix[2,1]],
name=df.index[2],
# marker=dict(color=cof_pal[2]
)


layout = go.Layout(showlegend=True, title="Title", font=dict(size=Chart_Title_Font_Size),
               yaxis=dict(title='Percentage Change(%)', titlefont=dict(size=yaxis_font_size), tickfont=dict(size=yaxis_font_size)),
               xaxis=dict(title='Time', titlefont=dict(size=xaxis_font_size), tickfont=dict(size=yaxis_font_size))
              )


data = [trace0,trace1,trace2]

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, filename='fig1')
```

I need the y axis to be x.xx% format (or n digits after the decimal point).

Another question is: the y axis title "Percentage Change(%)" is too close to the y axis numbers. How to move it further?

Comment: If you have two questions, ask separately

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could set [`tickformat`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-tickformat) in the `layout` options.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(tickformat=".2%"))
```

Comment: @Maximilian, what about if one wants to have integers as labels of x-axis? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628849/create-a-bar-chart-using-plotly

Comment: @maniA: for categorical values/strings `type='categorical'` can be used, see the detailed answer in the link.

Comment: Another option is to use the `update_yaxis` function like `fig.update_yaxes(tickformat="%")`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ticksuffix in the layout options.

```
yaxis=dict(ticksuffix=".00%")

layout = go.Layout(                
                yaxis=dict(ticksuffix=".00%", tickangle=45, title='Percentage Change(%)')
```

https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-yaxis

Answer (score 2):

After you've created your *fig* object you can use `fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat=".2%")`.

If someone didn't want a decimal or the numbers to the right of it showing they could use `"2%"`.