# create a bar chart using plotly

Tags: python, plotly, stacked-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart using `plotly`.

The input data looks like:

```
In [7]: datag.ix[:,0].tolist()[1:6]
Out[7]: [2020.0, 5000.0, 6010.0, 6017.0, 6020.0]
```

and

```
In [8]:datag.ix[:,1].tolist()[1:6]
Out[8]: 
[0.005178087393490427,
 0.0014053668695097226,
 0.3174139251746979,
 0.006049724003653125,
 0.24824287385322272]
```

and the code is

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.plotly as py 
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Bar(
        x=[str(x) for x in datag.ix[:,0].tolist()[1:6]],#datag.ix[:,0].tolist()[1:6],
        y=datag.ix[:,1].tolist()[1:6],
        name='travel'
        )
data=[trace1]
layout= go.Layout(
        barmode= 'stack',
        title='Realization: 0, 0',
        xaxis=dict(title='Model'),
        yaxis=dict(title='Time (minutes)')
        )
fig= go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
offline.plot(fig, image='png', filename='stacked-bar')
```

I get the following output:
[image]
However, the problem is I want to demonstrate the x-data just as strings
which I tried with `x=[str(x) for x in datag.ix[:,0].tolist()[1:6]]`.
Can some one help me to figure out how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotly 'assumes' your data type, even if you provide strings. Setting [`type`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-type) to `categorical` for your `xaxis` resp. `yaxis` in `layout` should do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.plotly as py 
import plotly.graph_objs as go

d = {'x': [None,
           2020.0, 
           5000.0, 
           6010.0, 
           6017.0, 
           6020.0], 
     'y': [None,
           0.005178087393490427,
           0.0014053668695097226,
           0.3174139251746979,
           0.006049724003653125,
           0.24824287385322272]}
datag = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=[str(x) for x in datag.ix[:,0].tolist()[1:6]],
    y=datag.ix[:,1].tolist()[1:6],
    name='travel')

data = [trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    title='Realization: 0, 0',
    xaxis=dict(title='Model', 
               type='category'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Time (minutes)'))
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
offline.plot(fig, image='png', filename='stacked-bar')
```

[image]