# Plot a density histogram with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm looking for a way to plot a density histogram with Plotly. As a `density=True` with a numpy histogram. My variable is a continuous one from 0 to 20. I already have a count on yaxis with bins. So I'm looking for replace theses counts by percentage (o density).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`go.Histogram(x=some_vec, histnorm="probability density")`

Comment: Kindly provide an explaination to the solution

Answer (score 0):

Give a try using the layout option:

```
layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(tickformat=".2%"))
```

You can see this question kind of duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582305/python-plotly-format-axis-numbers-as)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not directly computing the frequency adding this format. There is no way to tell him to compute frequencies instead of count per `nbinsx` ?